# How to use pycfslib

Tags: python

Best regard just obtain the pycfslib for python, somebody could get me an example to implement a code than permits open and load the file .cfs, I tried but it was impossible: the source is somethig like this:

import pycfslib

```
def loadFile(self):
    file, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Data", "")
    # data=np.loadtxt(file)
    data = pycfslib.read_cfs(file, True) # Here is the error

    self.x=data[:,0]
    self.y=data[:,1]
```

Later I need to pass the data to the vectors but shows this error:
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Thank you,